# jQuery On Click Requiring Two Clicks After The First

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked at similar questions and read the proposed solutions, but it seems each case regarding this issue is different.

Very simply when I press my menu icon the first time, my slideout menu appears.  Each time after the first requires two presses or two clicks to activate the slideout menu.

The jQuery -

```
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // create menu variables
    var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
    var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

    // toggle open class
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

    // slide menu
    if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: "0px"
        }); 
    } else {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: -slideoutMenuWidth
        }, 250);    
    }
});


$('.slideout-menu-close').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // create menu variables
    var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
    var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

    // toggle open class
    slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

    // slide menu
    if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {

        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: -slideoutMenuWidth
        }, 250);    

    } else {
        slideoutMenu.animate({
            left: "0px"
        }); 
    }

});
```

You can see a demo of the problem viewing through a smartphone at www.chrismazzochi.com.

Thanks for you help, 
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you toggle class before checking for class "open" using `hasClass()`. Just toggle class "open" after condition check.

Try this :

```
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // create menu variables
        var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
        var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

        // toggle open class
        slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

        // slide menu
        if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
            slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
        } else {
            slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: -slideoutMenuWidth
            }, 250);
        }
    });


    $('.slideout-menu-close').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // create menu variables
        var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
        var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

        // toggle open class
        if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {

            slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: -slideoutMenuWidth
            }, 250);

        } else {
            slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
        }
        // toogle class after condition check
        slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your suggestion.  It doesn't  work unfortunately.

Comment: It will work but you trying it wrong place you need to change your last code block while you edit first code block

Comment: Are you saying there is nothing wrong with the first function -

    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){ 

And that the issue lies within the close function?

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool, glad to help :)